# encrypting and decrypting an object by an self implemented crypter class

Tags: java, encryption

I got confused in an assignment :D 
given a UML diagram I had to Implement a course management application, one part is the Student class as follow

```
    public class Student extends Person implements Encryptable {
    private String program;
    private Vector<Course> courses;

//constructor. 
    public Student(String Name, String pnr, String tel, String prog) {
            super(Name, pnr, tel);
            program = prog;
            courses = new Vector<Course>();
        }
/* implementation of related methods 
  ......  */

        @Override
    public void encrypt(String password) {
    }

    @Override
    public void decrypt(String password) {  
    }
```

all other classes and all related setters and getters of this class are implemented  also the Encryptable interface is as follow

```
public interface Encryptable {

    public void encrypt(String password);
    public void decrypt(String password);
}
```

in an earlier task I had implemented a class "PassworCrypter" that I should use that class

```
public class PasswordCrypter {
    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;
    SecretKey key;
    DESKeySpec dks;
    SecretKeyFactory skf;
    byte[] psword;

    public PasswordCrypter(String password) {

        try {
            psword = password.getBytes("UTF-16");
            dks = new DESKeySpec(psword);
            skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            key = skf.generateSecret(dks);
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        }

    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] array) {

        try {
            return ecipher.doFinal(array);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        }
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] array) {

        try {
            return dcipher.doFinal(array);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new CrypterException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I should use PasswordCrypter class on local and inherited fields of the Student
class. When a Student object is encrypted it should not be possible to get data
such as a student's name without first calling decrypt. A Student object should
always be encrypted except for when you need to access any of its data.
can any one give me idea or tell me how should I encrypt this damn student :)

Comment: why do you crack up when asking your question? is it too funny?

Comment: Anybody who gave you that assignment is, sorry to say it, an idiot. A student is not an `Encryptable`. I've oodles of students living around me, and none have ever answered when I asked if they were `Encryptable`. Even if they were, it would be pretty tricky to decrypt them *after they already exist*. OO design like this is one of the banes of software management, and anybody who teaches such practices should be keelhauled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem in `Encryptable`. The signature of the method should be

```
public void encrypt(Encrypter enc);
public void decrypt(Decrypter dec);
```

Where you can define two separate interfaces `Encrypter` and `Decrypter`. so finally you can use `PasswordCrypter` as central class which implements these two methods.

```
 public class PasswordCrypter implements Encrypter,Decrypter  {
```

So now inside your Student class you can do

```
public void encrypt(Encrypter enc) {
   byte[] programbytes = enc.encrypt(program);
}

public void encrypt(Decrypter dec) {
   program = dec.decrypt(programbytes);
}
```

Comment: ye this is my main problem , this interface is given as a prat of assignment . and we shouldn't change it

Comment: If you can't change it then you will need to use your `PasswordCrypter ` instance inside each class :)

Comment: well thank you I think it works now , at least works in the Junit test if my Junit test works proper. dont still have any main ,